# How do I cast one Flex object as a derived type?

Tags: apache-flex

Here's the example:

```
var cartesian:CartesianChart = new CartesianChart(); 
cartesian.width = 100;
var column:ColumnChart = new ColumnChart();
column = cartesian as ColumnChart;
```

Why does this not work?  "column" ends up null.  ColumnChart is a derived class of CartesianChart, so I would have thought I'd end up with a ColumnChart with a width of 100.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to up-cast a CartesianChart to a ColumnChart - which won't be possible.  Are you trying to create a ColumnChart that always has a width of 100?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: the ultimate goal is a little convoluted to write out, but I was hoping to "up-cast" in order to reduce repetition in my code. (starting with a primitive chart, setting some values, then recasting and filling out properties available only to ColumnChart or PieChart or whatever the user selects.) I'm going to have to find another way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

ColumnChart `extends` CartesianChart?  I don't believe you can cast an object from a parent class to an object of it's child class. Your best bet is to write a class function on ColumnChart called something like `copyFromCartesianChart` that takes the CartesianChart object as a param and gets and sets all the props you need.

Comment: right, Column extends Cartesian.  Apparently you can only cast child as parent, shedding any properties that aren't inherited.  Good idea on extending the derived class with a method that accomplishes this.